# Backus Naur Form Assoicativity

Tags: bnf, associativity

Is this the correct way to implement right associativity for Exponentiation PowExp? So that 2^3^4 is actually (2^(3^4))

```
<Exp> ::= <Exp> + <MulExp>
| <Exp> - <MulExp>
| <MulExp>
<MulExp> ::= <MulExp> * <PowExp>
| <MulExp> / <PowExp>
| <PowExp>
<PowExp> ::= <NegExp> ^ <PowExp>
|<NegExp>
<NegExp> ::= - <RootExp>
| <RootExp>
<RootExp> ::= ( <Exp> )
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've written it is correct.

Incidentally, you might want to reconsider your hierarchy; in regular math, −3<sup>4</sup> is −(3<sup>4</sup>), not (−3)<sup>4</sup>. So you might want `- 3 ^ 4` to mean `- (3 ^ 4)`, in which case `NegExp` would include `PowExp` rather than the other way around. (But I suppose it could be confusing if `-3 ^ 4` means `-(3 ^ 4)`, so maybe there's no intuitive order-of-operations here? Another possibility is to require parentheses for *either* reading, by having `PowExp` and `NegExp` both depend directly on `RootExp`.)